# Channel behavior in subtest differs from production (unbuffered but receiving many times)

Tags: go, testing, channel, goroutine

I have this functionality that works well in production, and worked well in some basic tests. I have tried converting into a table-based test but I am getting issues. The code involved is fairly large for SO but I will try to sketch out the details:

The function "sendReadyUpPrompt":

```golang
func (w *webServer) sendReadyUpPrompt(m *Match) {
    for _, player := range w.getPlayerConns(m) {
        if player == nil {
            log.Println("Couldn't send rup signal to player (no connection object)", player)
        } else {
            player.sendJSON <- NewRupSignalMsg(true, false, w.rupTime)
        }
    }
    m.timer = time.NewTimer(time.Second * time.Duration(w.rupTime))
    m.Status = matchRupSignal
    
    p1 := m.players[0].Connection
    p2 := m.players[1].Connection
    p1ready := false
    p2ready := false
    for !(p1ready && p2ready) { //while not both players readied
        select {
            case <- m.timer.C: //Block until timer reaches maturity
                log.Println("Timer expired in rup. ready states:", p1ready, p2ready)
                w.expireRup(m, p1ready, p2ready)
                return
            case <- p1.playerReady:
                p1ready = true
                log.Println("player 1 has readied") //In production this only prints once, but in the table driven tests it prints multiple times per any given test.
            case <- p2.playerReady:
                p2ready = true
                log.Println("player 2 has readied")
        }
    }
    log.Println("both players have readied")
    w.expireRup(m, false, false)
    w.initializeMatch(m)
}
```

This waits for messages to come across two channels or a timer to expire to determine whether two players are ready for a game. It is run as a goroutine.
In a production environment, where I am sending on the playerReady channels like this:

```golang
if i receive a json message from a client called "ready" {
    conn.playerReady <- true
}
```

I get a normal output where one message of "player 2 has readied" is logged.
In a test environment I get something like this for test B but not for the other tests:

```
2023/01/01 21:07:31 player 2 has readied
2023/01/01 21:07:31 player 2 has readied
2023/01/01 21:07:31 player 2 has readied
2023/01/01 21:07:31 player 2 has readied
2023/01/01 21:07:31 player 2 has readied
2023/01/01 21:07:31 player 2 has readied
2023/01/01 21:07:31 player 2 has readied
2023/01/01 21:07:31 player 2 has readied
2023/01/01 21:07:31 player 2 has readied
2023/01/01 21:07:31 player 2 has readied
2023/01/01 21:07:31 player 2 has readied
2023/01/01 21:07:31 player 2 has readied
```

Interspersed with this I get messages from the objects in the previous tests that are closing

```
2023/01/01 21:20:51 Removed connection 1 from game hub //this should be logged after calling gameConn.Close() at the end of the previous subtest
2023/01/01 21:20:51 player 2 has readied
2023/01/01 21:20:51 player 2 has readied
2023/01/01 21:20:51 Removed connection Mario from user hub //same for this
```

How can that be? Shouldn't one test finish and its objects complete their Closing duties before the next test?

And now here is my embarrassing test

```golang
func TestTableRUP(t *testing.T) {
    type rupper map[string]int //key: id, int: seconds after signal to rup
    type exq map[string]bool

    var tests = []struct{
        name string
        responders rupper
        matchOrQueue string
        expectedQueue exq
    }{
        {name: "A", responders: make(rupper), matchOrQueue: "q", expectedQueue: make(exq)},
        {name: "B", responders: rupper{"Mario": 1}, matchOrQueue: "q", expectedQueue: exq{"Mario": true}},
        {name: "C", responders: rupper{"Mario": 1, "Luigi": 1}, matchOrQueue: "m", expectedQueue: make(exq)}, //after put in a match, q should be empty
        {name: "D", responders: rupper{"Mario": 1, "Luigi": 6}, matchOrQueue: "q", expectedQueue: exq{"Mario": true}},
    }
    for _, test := range tests {
        test := test
        t.Run(test.name, func(t *testing.T) {
            t.Log("~~~~~~~~~~~~~Running test", test.name)
            mgeme := newWebServer()
            //these lines create a gin engine I can connect to with createOneUser
            sv := createServerHandler(mgeme, defaultErrHandler, t)
            //launch the engine and create a user's game server (necessary for the test)
            gameConn, server := createServerAndGameConns(sv, t)
            //create two users using websocket.DefaultDialer.Dial()
            wsConnA := createOneUser(t, server, "Luigi")
            wsConnB := createOneUser(t, server, "Mario")
            
            //Add two players to queue
            players := make(map[string]*connection)
            var mario *connection
            var luigi *connection
            
            player_cond := func() bool {
                mario, _ = mgeme.playerHub.findConnection("Mario")
                luigi, _ = mgeme.playerHub.findConnection("Luigi")
                return mario != nil && luigi != nil
            }
            
            require.Eventuallyf(t, player_cond, 1 * time.Second, 1 * time.Millisecond, "Player conns shouldn't be nil in test %s", test.name)
            //put my two players in a gamequeue so when i send a ready up signal they can receive it
            mgeme.queueUpdate(true, mario)
            mgeme.queueUpdate(true, luigi)
            players["Mario"] = mario
            players["Luigi"] = luigi
            //create a match using the two players in the queue
            match, err := mgeme.dummyMatch()
            require.NoErrorf(t, err, "Error forming dummy match: %v", err)
            //send ready up prompt to the two players in the queue
            go mgeme.sendReadyUpPrompt(match)
            //one of the players will wait for a json message here so they know to respond to the rup signal
            msg := readWaitFor(wsConnA, "RupSignal", t, false)
            var rs RupSignal
            json.Unmarshal(msg, &rs)
            t.Logf("Rup signal: %v", rs)
            expected_rs := NewRupSignalMsg(true, false, mgeme.rupTime)
            require.EqualValues(t, expected_rs, rs, "Rup signal value not what was expected")

            //each player will now respond (on time or late) or ignore the signal.
            var wg sync.WaitGroup
            for id, conn := range players { 
                wg.Add(1)
                go func(id string, conn *connection) { //<------------- potentially of interest
                    defer wg.Done()
                    seconds, exists := test.responders[id] //see how many seconds each player should wait before responding for this test
                    if exists {
                        <-time.After(time.Duration(seconds) * time.Second) //wait either 1 or 6 seconds (at 5, the ready up signal expires and the player's ready signal is ignored (that blocks due to being unbuffered but thats unrelated to this question at this point. in the tests where the players respond on time or dont respond at all i am getting odd behavior)
                        t.Log("Sending rup signal....")
                        conn.playerReady <- true //<------------- potentially of interest
                    }
                }(id, conn)
            }
            wg.Wait()
            //here i am testing how the server has handled a cancelled ready up signal
            //players that ready upped should be placed back in the queue but the 
            //ones who didnt should be left out
            queue_cond := func() bool {
                mgeme.queueMutex.RLock()
                _, mq := mgeme.gameQueue["Mario"]
                _, lq := mgeme.gameQueue["Luigi"]
                mgeme.queueMutex.RUnlock()
                return (test.expectedQueue["Mario"] == mq && test.expectedQueue["Luigi"] == lq)
            }
            require.Eventuallyf(t, queue_cond, 5500 * time.Millisecond, 10*time.Millisecond, "Queues should be equal in test %s", test.name)
            //in one of the tests we don't just want to know the queue, we want to know if the match creation processes completed when both players readied in time
            if test.matchOrQueue == "m" {
                _, obj := mgeme.gameServerHub.findConnection("1")
                <-time.After(500 * time.Millisecond)
                require.True(t, obj.(*gameServer).findMatchByPlayer("Mario") != -1)
            }
            
            gameConn.Close()
            wsConnA.Close()
            wsConnB.Close()
            server.Close()
        })
    }
}
```

To some my question up, look again at the part of my test where i have a goroutine send, at most, one message on .playerReady per player. But my test logs out a lot of messages that it received this. What is causing this discrepancy between my production execution and my test?

Comment: Code is too long to analyze, but the behavior is consistent with `p2.playerReady` being closed. If you start goroutines in a test, make sure they are done before test returns. They will continue running otherwise.

Comment: @BurakSerdar Wouldn't I get a panic: sending on closed channel?

Comment: If you sent, yes. But the code that sends runs only once. If the channel is closed somewhere not shown in your code, this behavior may happen. This can also happen if you have multiple tests, and tests share resources.